Where can I store my bike travel case while I am off riding my bike?
I travel with my bike once a year and am wondering where to store my case?  I don't stay in one particular spot, but fly in and out of the same airport.
I build my bike up at the airport and ride out from there and break it down at a nearby hotel.
I have typically used cardboard boxes in the past and while that has served me well, I recently had an issue with United mishandling my bike box by not securing it properly in cargo such that it became jammed in the cargo door and they were unable to open the door until after forcing the door open mechanically.
If I travel with a hard case, where can I store it then?
If I know the hotel I will be traveling out of ahead of time, I could ask to store it there, but it might be 2 weeks and it would be a little bit long for them to hold it.
In the case of the airport, I could perhaps try to lock the case to a bike rack, but again, I am pretty sure the case would disappear.
Well then, what are best my options?

Many airports have left luggage offices, sometimes as well as luggage lockers. If there is a staffed office they might take in your bike case. Calling ahead will be needed to be sure.
Calling a nearby hotel asking if and for how long they will store your case will be an option, you might need to call several hotels before you find one that takes it.
An other option might be a self storage company, those mostly have standardized room(lets) which they rent out for standard periods but often work out much cheaper than left luggage offices when you need to store something for weeks.
Before you make your calls, have the actual outside size of the case, at least those they give you before buying but better still measure it yourself as well. And have the size in the measurements the people you call expect or in both metric and feet and inches.
